# Convert odd numbers to boolean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to convert a column in pandas:

```
A 
1
2
3
4
```

To another column which converts odd numbers to boolean:

```
A is_odd
1 True
2 False
3 True
4 False
```

I was thinking of using this code which doesn't work:

```
data["is_odd"] = not(bool(data["A"].mod(2)))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `(df % 2).astype(bool)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df['is_odd'] = df['A'] % 2 == 1
print (df)
   A  is_odd
0  1    True
1  2   False
2  3    True
3  4   False
```

Similar solution from @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:

```
df['is_odd'] = df['A'].mod(2).astype(bool)
```

Or:

```
df['is_odd'] = (df['A'] & 1).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks! Any way to use the mod() function?

Comment: Check second solution.